# Why there is no Singleton concept for Action class in Struts2?

Tags: struts2

I was going through differences of Struts1 vs Struts2, and came across this point:

- Struts 1 Actions are singletons and must be thread-safe since there will only be one instance of a class to handle all requests for that Action.
- Struts 2 Action objects are instantiated for each request, so there are no thread-safety issues.

Now my question is: in Struts2, why there are no singleton concept for Action class? As I think because, unnecessarily, there is more Object creation for every request.
Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Object creation is ridiculously fast in Java. Programming thread-safe action classes (and servlets, etc.) is irritating and error-prone.

Like with everything, there's a trade-off.

Comment: @NagappaLM I don't understand the question. Servlet are singletons, Struts 2 actions aren't.

Answer (score 0):

New instance in the sense, its not creating new object but jvm will create instance of that object hence there is no matter that how many request is comming for a particular object...even if the instance is more, the applcation will not hang...